# Is there a limit in Android on number of email address from contacts that I can fetch?

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am making an Android app where when a user starts typing email address, he gets autocomplete suggestions from his phone contact book.

If I put a limit on my code to fetch only **100** address, it works perfectly fine. If I don't put any limit, the app freezes. I haven't tried to put a higher limit and see and what point it gives up.

How can I optimize my code?

```
    private ArrayList<String> getNameEmailDetails() {
    ArrayList<String> emlRecs = new ArrayList<String>();
    **int count = 0;** // THIS IS ADDITIONAL

    HashSet<String> emlRecsHS = new HashSet<String>();
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };
    String order = "CASE WHEN " 
            + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
            + " NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, " 
            + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
            + ", " 
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
            + " COLLATE NOCASE";
    String filter = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " NOT LIKE ''";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, filter, null, order);
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String emlAddr = cur.getString(3);

            // keep unique only
            if (emlRecsHS.add(emlAddr.toLowerCase())) {
                emlRecs.add(emlAddr);
                **count++;** // THIS IS ADDITIONAL
            }
        } while (cur.moveToNext() **&& count < 100**);
    }

    cur.close();
    return emlRecs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app "freezes" because you are performing long-running or complicated calculations on the UI Thread. This is the Thread responsible for drawing your app's views and responding to user input.

You should move requests like this (as with all network activity) to another thread to keep your app from becoming unresponsive.

Look into [Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to address these restrictions.